# sharedPref.getString() picking value from ListPreference's entries instead of entryValues

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, listpreference

I have a `ListPreference` in my activity:

```
<ListPreference
        android:key="pref_rValue"
        android:entries="@array/r"
        android:summary="***"
        android:entryValues="@array/rValues"
        android:title="Choose"
        android:defaultValue="2"/>
```

whose `android:entries="@array/r"` and `android:entryValues="@array/rValues"` are defined separately in `strings.xml` like this:

```
    <string-array name="r">
        <item>0.5 km</item>
        <item>1 km</item>
        <item>2 km</item>
        <item>5 km</item>
        <item>10 km</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="rValues">
        <item>0.5</item>
        <item>1.0</item>
        <item>2.0</item>
        <item>5.0</item>
        <item>10.0</item>
    </string-array>
```

Key defined in `SettingActivity`: `public static final String KEY_PREF_SYNC_CONN = "pref_rValue";`

Here's how I'm using the key and then trying to get the value of this ListPreference in `MainActivity`:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String rValue = sharedPref.getString(SettingsActivity.KEY_PREF_SYNC_CONN, "5");
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "rValue: " + rValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

but when I'm trying to use `rValue` string as a `Double`, I'm getting this error: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "2 km"` and the Toast above is also showing `"rValue: 2 km"`.

I want to know that why instead of taking value from `android:entryValues="@array/rValues"`, it is taking value from `android:entries="@array/r"`?

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Have you tried swapping the android:entries and  android:entryValues in the XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a really simple and silly issue.

I just uninstalled the app and after installing it again, everything worked fine.

But, I would love to know that how to ensure that something like this doesn't happen in the future again.